# Android: drop down navigation showing a dialog in ActionBar

Tags: android, navigation, drop-down-menu, actionbarsherlock

I'd like to know whether it's possible to implement a drop down navigation style (the title with the little arrow in the bottom right corner) and when the user clicks, instead of displaying the drop-down list itself, showing a dialog.

Do I have to override any method of the SherlockActivity?
Now I can only do this when the user clicks in the home button doing the following:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
                ...
                }
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a button in the action bar as the custom navigation which has a background image that is the same as the spinner. When clicked, show a dialog.

Be careful, though, as you are changing the expected behavior of a standard action bar control which might be jarring to users.

Comment: indeed that's what I did, trying to mimic the original Action Bar with the drop-down navigation as good as possible.. thanks!